# How to use delta milliseconds to do something every x milliseconds?

Tags: timing, delta, timedelta

I'm using a timing system where I get delta (the number of milliseconds that passed every frame, 60 fps).

Before I used timing, I counted the frames and did something like this:

```
if(frames % 60 == 0) /*do something*/;
frames++;
```

But I can't use the same thing with delta:

```
if(milliseconds % 1000 == 0) /*do something*/;
milliseconds += delta;
```

Delta changes every time, and milliseconds won't be exactly a multiple of 1000 every second.

(I'm using Java, but that's not really relevant.)

Edit:

The if(milliseconds - prev_milliseconds >= 1000) from Stas Makutin works for the most part.
But in a part of my code, there is something like this:

```
if(frames % 60 == 0){ 
  ...
}
if(frames % 60 == 30){
  ...
}

if(frames % 40 == 0){
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this without using prev_millisecond1, prev_millisecond2, etc. (I.e. multiple prev_millisecond variables.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this will work:

```
prev_milliseconds = 0;

...

if (milliseconds - prev_milliseconds >= 1000) 
{
   /* do somthing */
   prev_milliseconds = milliseconds;
}
milliseconds += delta;
```

But if your code still triggers after each frame why not to continue count frames and use your old code?

Comment: I used to just count frames, but I wanted to add more accurate timing (because my program runs at different speeds on different computers). The speed that all the objects move at used to be pixels/frames, but now I'm changing everything to pixels/seconds.